# How can I limit access to a website that is deployed in a gke cluster to only be accessible by an IP range?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

How can I limit access to a website (sonar) that is deployed in a gke cluster to only be accessible by an IP range??

Can I do it with an Internal LoadBalancer?? Or do I have to enable Network Policy?

Comment: use a firewall.

Comment: Have you tried checking on this docs? [Creating a private cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters?hl=en) and [GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check nginx-ingress with the following annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range
```

Another option check [cloud armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview).

Third-party [example](https://medium.com/@lynnlin827/use-cloud-armor-to-restrict-ip-access-on-kubernetes-57ca221f43f0)
.